# Mail bouncing back after renaming AD user

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange

I am having user1 with mail address user1@xyz.com. Due to some contract agreement I have disabled user1 & created new AD account & email address as user2@xyz.com for the same user. This user has used this ad account & email address for 2 days. But as we were facing problem with other applications so we decided to give him old account & email address with rename it as user2 and added additional smtp address as user2@xyz.com. Before renaming old AD account (user1) we have deleted user2 & mail box. 
Now whenever we are sending email to this account using user2@xyz.com then it is bouncing back with error as "The e-mail address you entered couldn't be found. Please check the recipient's e-mail address and try to resend the message. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk." & "#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found ##".
We are able to send mail to this user if we use user1@xyz.com but not with new rename ID user2@xyz.com. If user is sending email to me and if I reply to this email then he is receiving the mail in his mailbox.

Comment: Delete the entries in your Outlook nickname/autocomplete cache for the failing email address.

Comment: If it is for 1 user I would have done that and resolved the issue. But user has used his email id (user2@xyz.com) for 2 days and many users are already sending email to him using this email id and now after deleting and adding new smtp address (user2@xyz.com) in user1@xyz.com, mails are bouncing back to users.